# How to explain behaviour of QApplication's app.exec();

Tags: qt

The following piece of code will cause `MainWindow` to open and immediately close again:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()); //just to be complete...
    if (app.arguments().size() == 1)
    {
        MainWindow mainWin;
        mainWin.show();
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

while the following version, which is identical to me, shows the `MainWindow` as expected:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()); //just to be complete...
    if (app.arguments().size() == 1)
    {
        MainWindow mainWin;
        mainWin.show();
        return app.exec();
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you have the `MainWindow` in a block, when that block ends everything created inside of it is automatically destroyed before you enter the application event loop. In the second case the block will end only after the application's event loop is halted.

```
if (app.arguments().size() == 1)
{
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
} // mainWin is destroyed here
return app.exec();
```